# wxwidgets detect mouse click on another window

Tags: linux, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is it possible to detect a double click on another window in wxwidgets?

In my quest to switch to linux I wanna build a program that reacts to double click on the desktop and the file manager and displays a menu.

Same as listary does on Windows.

Is this something that can be done with wxwidgets (preferably wxpython) under linux? What about on Windows?

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help: https://www.codeproject.com/messages/1822262/how-to-detect-double-click-on-desktop-window.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can't receive mouse clicks, or any other events, for windows of another process unless you capture the mouse (and never release it, which would be a bad idea).

Comment: I only want to act on double click on an empty space on the desktop and file manager, the rest will behave the same, since double clicking an empty space does nothing it shouldn't break anything, or are there other concerns. In windows it is possible since listary does just that, don't know if linux desktops/file managers have an empty space area that can be detected.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use FindWindow() and then Bind() the event handler.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on how to use it. I tried
`print(wx.FindWindowById(12832))` 12832 being a PID from task manager under Windows, but that returns "None". 
Also wx.FindWindow(12832) gives me "module 'wx' has no attribute 'FindWindow'"